# ERROR: imaplib.IMAP4.error: UID command error: BAD [b'Command Argument Error. 11']

Tags: python, outlook, imaplib

I made a program to run a function every time a new email is received. The IMAP server, connection and inbox work as intended. it is also not an issue with the whole `'"Inbox"'` vs `'Inbox'` format. I have tried almost everything I could think of with little to no success.

My code:

```
def connect():
    global connected
    #sets up connection with imap server
    connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com")
    try:
        (retcode, capabilities) = connection.login(login, secure_password)
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info()[1])
        sys.exit(1)
    
    print("connection successful")
    connected = True    
    return connection

def disconnect(connection):
    connection.logout()
    connected = False

connection = connect()

while connected == True:   
    print("Searching for new Emails...")         
    connection.select(mailbox = "Inbox", readonly=False)
    # test section start
    result, data_for_update = connection.uid('search', None, "ALL")
    ids = data_for_update[0]
    id_list = ids.split()
    if data_for_update[0].split()[-1] == latest_email_uid:
        print('No new emails found. search again in 5 minutes')
        time.sleep(300)
    else:
        result, data_for_update = connection.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
        raw_email = data_for_update[0],[1]
        latest_email_uid == data_for_update[0].split()[-1]
        print('New email found')
        time.sleep(300)
```

I tried to  program to run the code above. But when I run it, it returns this error:

```
\lib\imaplib.py", line 1055, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.IMAP4.error: UID command error: BAD [b'Command Argument Error. 11']
```